# VirtualBox removal stuck in purgatory

Tags: fedora, uninstall, dnf

I screwed up the uninstallation of VirtualBox on Fedora 30 and now it is "not installed" but I cannot reinstall it (the intent was to downgrade to 5.* because of an issue with the kernels). The files no longer exist but the understanding by the OS is that it is still there. The question: How can I remove  this installation?

`sudo dnf remove VirtualBox-6.0`

outputs

```
Remove  1 Package

Freed space: 238 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1/1 
  Running scriptlet: VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_fedora29-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                       1/1 
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5IEwko: line 6: /usr/lib/virtualbox/prerm-common.sh: No such file or directory
error: %preun(VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_fedora29-1.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package VirtualBox-6.0
  Verifying        : VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_fedora29-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                       1/1 

Failed:
  VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_fedora29-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                              

Error: Transaction failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if any VirtualBox processes are still running, and if so kill them:

```
sudo ps aux | grep -i "vbox"
sudo pkill VBox*
```

Try to uninstall VirtualBox with purge (maybe even with `--force-all`):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
```

If this does not work, check if synaptic can see any trace of VirtualBox,
since it can remove any `.deb` package, even if installed with `dpkg`.

To manually remove all installed files:

```
sudo /opt/VirtualBox/uninstall.sh
sudo rm -rf /opt/VirtualBox/
```

To delete all virtual machines and settings and Virtual hard drives:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/"VirtualBox VMs"
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/VirtualBox/
```

Comment: Fedora, not Ubuntu. Thanks anyways

Comment: Most of it should still apply, not so?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge` -> No. Even so, in the question I stated that a standard removal attempt failed.  `...check if synaptic can see...` I don't even know what this is, presumably something Ubuntu software manager. `To manually remove all installed files` Files no longer exist. It's like you didn't even read the question.

Comment: How can I know which files no longer exist if this isn't specified? Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/835407/963426)  for creating the file `prerm-common.sh` that is blocking according to the error message.